Optaplanner v8.23 groupBy with ConstraintCollectors.toList() not working as expected
I am working on an employee rostering application. I am trying to implement a number of constraints which have to do with consecutive days of work. Let's take as an example the constraint for minimum consecutive days of work i.e. I want to penalize shifts which are in clusters of less than 3 consecutive working days. 3 would be variable and user selected.
I am experiencing 2 kinds of problems..
The constraint I've put together is the following:
Constraint minConsecutiveDays(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory
                .forEach(Shift.class)
                .groupBy(shift -> shift)  // Hack I found on the internet
                .groupBy(Shift::getEmployee, ConstraintCollectors.toList())
                .filter((employee, shifts) -> {
                    // TODO: for debug only
                    if (shifts.size() == 1) {
                        if (shifts.get(0).getEmployee() == null) {
                            System.out.println("Wrong shift grouping! Employee: " + employee
                                    + " grouped to shift with null employee ");
                            return false;
                        }
                        if (employee != shifts.get(0).getEmployee()) {
                            System.out.println("Wrong shift grouping! Employee: " + employee
                                    + " grouped to shifts: " + shifts + " which have assigned employees: "
                                    + shifts.get(0).getEmployee().getName());
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (shifts.size() > 1) {
                        // Check first shift
                        if (shifts.get(0).getEmployee() == null) {
                            System.out.println("Wrong shift grouping! Employee: " + employee
                                    + " grouped to shift with null employee ");
                            return false;
                        }
                        if (employee != shifts.get(0).getEmployee()) {
                            System.out.println("Wrong shift grouping! Employee: " + employee
                                    + " grouped to shifts: " + shifts + " which have assigned employees: "
                                    + shifts.get(0).getEmployee().getName());
                            return false;
                        }
                        // Check remaining shifts
                        for (int i = 1; i < shifts.size(); ++i) {
                            Shift previousShift = shifts.get(i-1);
                            Shift currentShift = shifts.get(i);

                            if (currentShift.getEmployee() == null) {
                                System.out.println("Wrong shift grouping! Employee: " + employee
                                        + " grouped to shift with null employee ");
                                return false;
                            }
                            if (employee != currentShift.getEmployee() ||
                                    previousShift.getEmployee() != currentShift.getEmployee()) {
                                System.out.println("Wrong shift grouping! Employee: " + employee
                                        + " grouped to shifts: " + shifts + " which have assigned employees: "
                                        + shifts.stream().map(s -> {
                                            if (s.getEmployee() != null) {
                                                return s.getEmployee().getName();
                                            } else {
                                                return "null";
                                            }
                                }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                })
                .flattenLast((List<Shift> employeeShifts) -> keepShiftsViolatingMinConsecutiveDays(
                        employeeShifts, 3))
                .penalizeConfigurable(CONSTRAINT_MIN_CONSECUTIVE_DAYS);
    }

private List<Shift> keepShiftsViolatingMinConsecutiveDays(List<Shift> employeeShifts, int minConsecutiveDays) {
        List<Shift> shiftsViolatingMinConsecutiveDays = new ArrayList<>();

        // Sort shifts by start date/time
        List<Shift> sortedShifts = employeeShifts.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Shift::getStartDateTime))
                .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList());

        int consecutiveCount = 1;
        ArrayList<Shift> consecutiveDaysShifts = new ArrayList<>();
        consecutiveDaysShifts.add(sortedShifts.get(0));

        for (int i = 1; i < sortedShifts.size(); ++i) {
            Shift firstShift = sortedShifts.get(i-1);
            Shift secondShift = sortedShifts.get(i);
            LocalDate firstDay = firstShift.getStartDateTime().toLocalDate();
            LocalDate secondDay = secondShift.getStartDateTime().toLocalDate();

            // Two shifts on the same day --> ignore 2nd shift (i.e. no counter incrementing) and continue
            if (firstDay.isEqual(secondDay)) {
                consecutiveDaysShifts.add(secondShift);
                continue;
            }

            if (firstDay.plusDays(1).isEqual(secondDay)) {
                // Consecutive day found
                consecutiveDaysShifts.add(secondShift);
                consecutiveCount++;
            } else {
                // Gap day discovered
                if (consecutiveCount < minConsecutiveDays) {
                    shiftsViolatingMinConsecutiveDays.addAll(consecutiveDaysShifts);
                }
                consecutiveCount = 1;
                consecutiveDaysShifts.clear();
                consecutiveDaysShifts.add(secondShift);
            }
        }

        // Consider last consecutive days found
        if (consecutiveCount < minConsecutiveDays) {
            shiftsViolatingMinConsecutiveDays.addAll(consecutiveDaysShifts);
        }

        return shiftsViolatingMinConsecutiveDays;
    }


In order to retrieve/count consecutive days for each employee I couldn't come up with a different alternative to 'ConstraintCollectors.toList()' although I know it is a performance killer. Let me know if you can think of a cleverer way to do it..
1st problem:
The behavior I would expect after the .groupBy(Shift::getEmployee, ConstraintCollectors.toList()) is that for each employee (not null ones) I would get all the shifts the employee is assigned to. However this is not always the case. This is why I have written some error catching logic in the filter section following the groupBy. If I am not mistaken the execution should not enter any of the if statements there. Yet it does! Many times. I should note that this is observed while the solver is running.
2nd problem:
After I introduce this new constraint with the groupBy I observe weird/wrong behavior in other constraints. As an example think of the following arrangement:

I have 3 8-hour shifts per day for 6 days in a row.
I have only 4 employees available (E1-E4).
Unassigned shifts are -1 medium.
The only other constraint interfering is the max hours (8) of work per day (hard). Penalty=-(daily hours over 8 hours).

I am debugging with TRACE and observing the construction heuristics phase (first fit). The output i get before i introduce the new constraint, for the first 2 days, is the following:
2024-09-24 12:50:41,744 INFO  [org.opt.cor.imp.sol.DefaultSolver] (pool-24-thread-1) Solving started: time spent (16), best score (0hard/-18medium/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE), random (JDK with seed 0).
2024-09-24 12:50:41,788 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (0), score (0hard/-18medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 {null -> null}).
2024-09-24 12:50:41,803 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (1), score (0hard/-17medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 {null -> Nicoletta Braschi (E1)}).
2024-09-24 12:50:41,809 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (2), score (0hard/-17medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 {null -> Roberto Benigni (E2)}).
2024-09-24 12:50:41,814 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (3), score (0hard/-17medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 {null -> Monica Bellucci (E3)}).
2024-09-24 12:50:41,817 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (4), score (0hard/-17medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 {null -> Marcello Mastroianni (E4)}).
2024-09-24 12:50:41,821 DEBUG [org.opt.cor.imp.con.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-24-thread-1)     CH step (0), time spent (94), score (0hard/-17medium/0soft), selected move count (5), picked move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 {null -> Nicoletta Braschi (E1)}).
2024-09-24 12:50:41,826 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (0), score (0hard/-17medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 {null -> null}).
2024-09-24 12:50:57,642 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (1), score (-480hard/-16medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 {null -> Nicoletta Braschi (E1)}).
2024-09-24 12:50:57,645 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (2), score (0hard/-16medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 {null -> Roberto Benigni (E2)}).
2024-09-24 12:50:57,649 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (3), score (0hard/-16medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 {null -> Monica Bellucci (E3)}).
2024-09-24 12:50:57,652 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (4), score (0hard/-16medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 {null -> Marcello Mastroianni (E4)}).
2024-09-24 12:50:57,654 DEBUG [org.opt.cor.imp.con.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-24-thread-1)     CH step (1), time spent (15927), score (0hard/-16medium/0soft), selected move count (5), picked move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 {null -> Roberto Benigni (E2)}).
2024-09-24 12:50:57,658 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (0), score (0hard/-16medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 {null -> null}).
2024-09-24 12:51:06,117 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (1), score (-480hard/-15medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 {null -> Nicoletta Braschi (E1)}).
2024-09-24 12:51:08,775 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (2), score (-480hard/-15medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 {null -> Roberto Benigni (E2)}).
2024-09-24 12:51:08,778 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (3), score (0hard/-15medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 {null -> Monica Bellucci (E3)}).
2024-09-24 12:51:08,780 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (4), score (0hard/-15medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 {null -> Marcello Mastroianni (E4)}).
2024-09-24 12:51:08,782 DEBUG [org.opt.cor.imp.con.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-24-thread-1)     CH step (2), time spent (27055), score (0hard/-15medium/0soft), selected move count (5), picked move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 {null -> Monica Bellucci (E3)}).
2024-09-24 12:51:08,784 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (0), score (0hard/-15medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 {null -> null}).
2024-09-24 12:51:08,786 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (1), score (0hard/-14medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 {null -> Nicoletta Braschi (E1)}).
2024-09-24 12:51:08,788 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (2), score (0hard/-14medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 {null -> Roberto Benigni (E2)}).
2024-09-24 12:51:08,792 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (3), score (0hard/-14medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 {null -> Monica Bellucci (E3)}).
2024-09-24 12:51:08,794 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-24-thread-1)         Move index (4), score (0hard/-14medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 {null -> Marcello Mastroianni (E4)}).
2024-09-24 12:51:08,797 DEBUG [org.opt.cor.imp.con.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-24-thread-1)     CH step (3), time spent (27069), score (0hard/-14medium/0soft), selected move count (5), picked move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 {null -> Nicoletta Braschi (E1)}).
...         Move index (0), score (0hard/-14medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 {null -> null}).
...         Move index (1), score (-480hard/-13medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 {null -> Nicoletta Braschi (E1)}).
...         Move index (2), score (0hard/-13medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 {null -> Roberto Benigni (E2)}).
...         Move index (3), score (0hard/-13medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 {null -> Monica Bellucci (E3)}).
...         Move index (4), score (0hard/-13medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 {null -> Marcello Mastroianni (E4)}).
...     CH step (4), time spent (75839), score (0hard/-13medium/0soft), selected move count (5), picked move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 {null -> Roberto Benigni (E2)}).
...         Move index (0), score (0hard/-13medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-03T06:00+02:00 {null -> null}).
...         Move index (1), score (-480hard/-12medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-03T06:00+02:00 {null -> Nicoletta Braschi (E1)}).
...         Move index (2), score (-480hard/-12medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-03T06:00+02:00 {null -> Roberto Benigni (E2)}).
...         Move index (3), score (0hard/-12medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-03T06:00+02:00 {null -> Monica Bellucci (E3)}).
...         Move index (4), score (0hard/-12medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-03T06:00+02:00 {null -> Marcello Mastroianni (E4)}).
...     CH step (5), time spent (107790), score (0hard/-12medium/0soft), selected move count (5), picked move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-03T06:00+02:00 {null -> Monica Bellucci (E3)}).

which is as expected. However when I introduce the min-consecutive days constraints the penalty (hard) calculations are spiraling out of control and do not make any sense to me:
2024-09-24 13:04:57,485 INFO  [org.opt.cor.imp.sol.DefaultSolver] (pool-34-thread-1) Solving started: time spent (7), best score (0hard/-18medium/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE), random (JDK with seed 0).
2024-09-24 13:04:57,496 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (0), score (0hard/-18medium/0soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 {null -> null}).
2024-09-24 13:05:02,449 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (1), score (0hard/-17medium/-100soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 {null -> Nicoletta Braschi (E1)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:03,498 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (2), score (0hard/-17medium/-100soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 {null -> Roberto Benigni (E2)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:04,179 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (3), score (0hard/-17medium/-100soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 {null -> Monica Bellucci (E3)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:05,058 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (4), score (0hard/-17medium/-100soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 {null -> Marcello Mastroianni (E4)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:05,059 DEBUG [org.opt.cor.imp.con.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-34-thread-1)     CH step (0), time spent (7581), score (0hard/-17medium/-100soft), selected move count (5), picked move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 {null -> Nicoletta Braschi (E1)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:10,320 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (0), score (0hard/-17medium/-100soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 {null -> null}).
2024-09-24 13:05:13,839 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (1), score (-480hard/-16medium/-200soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 {null -> Nicoletta Braschi (E1)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:17,591 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (2), score (-480hard/-16medium/-200soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 {null -> Roberto Benigni (E2)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:20,071 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (3), score (-480hard/-16medium/-200soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 {null -> Monica Bellucci (E3)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:21,856 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (4), score (-960hard/-16medium/-200soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 {null -> Marcello Mastroianni (E4)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:21,856 DEBUG [org.opt.cor.imp.con.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-34-thread-1)     CH step (1), time spent (24378), score (0hard/-17medium/-100soft), selected move count (5), picked move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 {null -> null}).
2024-09-24 13:05:21,857 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (0), score (-960hard/-17medium/-200soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 {null -> null}).
2024-09-24 13:05:24,477 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (1), score (-1440hard/-16medium/-300soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 {null -> Nicoletta Braschi (E1)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:26,545 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (2), score (-1440hard/-16medium/-300soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 {null -> Roberto Benigni (E2)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:27,754 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (3), score (-1440hard/-16medium/-300soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 {null -> Monica Bellucci (E3)}).
Wrong shift grouping! Employee: Marcello Mastroianni (E4) grouped to shift with null employee 
2024-09-24 13:05:28,363 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (4), score (-1920hard/-16medium/-100soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 {null -> Marcello Mastroianni (E4)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:28,363 DEBUG [org.opt.cor.imp.con.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-34-thread-1)     CH step (2), time spent (30885), score (-960hard/-17medium/-200soft), selected move count (5), picked move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-01T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 {null -> null}).
2024-09-24 13:05:28,364 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (0), score (-1920hard/-17medium/-100soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 {null -> null}).
2024-09-24 13:05:29,722 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (1), score (-1920hard/-16medium/-200soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 {null -> Nicoletta Braschi (E1)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:31,005 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (2), score (-1920hard/-16medium/-200soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 {null -> Roberto Benigni (E2)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:31,720 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (3), score (-1920hard/-16medium/-200soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 {null -> Monica Bellucci (E3)}).
Wrong shift grouping! Employee: Marcello Mastroianni (E4) grouped to shift with null employee 
2024-09-24 13:05:31,724 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (4), score (-1920hard/-16medium/-100soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 {null -> Marcello Mastroianni (E4)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:31,725 DEBUG [org.opt.cor.imp.con.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-34-thread-1)     CH step (3), time spent (34247), score (-1920hard/-16medium/-100soft), selected move count (5), picked move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T06:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 {null -> Marcello Mastroianni (E4)}).
Wrong shift grouping! Employee: Marcello Mastroianni (E4) grouped to shift with null employee 
2024-09-24 13:05:39,162 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (0), score (-2400hard/-16medium/-100soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 {null -> null}).
2024-09-24 13:05:39,772 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (1), score (-2400hard/-15medium/-200soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 {null -> Nicoletta Braschi (E1)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:42,564 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (2), score (-2400hard/-15medium/-200soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 {null -> Roberto Benigni (E2)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:44,131 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (3), score (-2880hard/-15medium/-200soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 {null -> Monica Bellucci (E3)}).
Wrong shift grouping! Employee: Marcello Mastroianni (E4) grouped to shift with null employee 
2024-09-24 13:05:45,084 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (4), score (-3360hard/-15medium/-100soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 {null -> Marcello Mastroianni (E4)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:45,085 DEBUG [org.opt.cor.imp.con.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-34-thread-1)     CH step (4), time spent (47607), score (-2400hard/-15medium/-200soft), selected move count (5), picked move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T14:00+02:00 to 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 {null -> Nicoletta Braschi (E1)}).
Wrong shift grouping! Employee: Marcello Mastroianni (E4) grouped to shift with null employee 
2024-09-24 13:05:45,996 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (0), score (-3360hard/-15medium/-200soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-03T06:00+02:00 {null -> null}).
2024-09-24 13:05:47,766 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (1), score (-3840hard/-14medium/-300soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-03T06:00+02:00 {null -> Nicoletta Braschi (E1)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:49,227 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (2), score (-3360hard/-14medium/-300soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-03T06:00+02:00 {null -> Roberto Benigni (E2)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:51,005 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (3), score (-3840hard/-14medium/-300soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-03T06:00+02:00 {null -> Monica Bellucci (E3)}).
Wrong shift grouping! Employee: Marcello Mastroianni (E4) grouped to shift with null employee 
2024-09-24 13:05:51,931 TRACE [org.opt.cor.imp.con.dec.ConstructionHeuristicDecider] (pool-34-thread-1)         Move index (4), score (-4320hard/-14medium/-200soft), move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-03T06:00+02:00 {null -> Marcello Mastroianni (E4)}).
2024-09-24 13:05:51,932 DEBUG [org.opt.cor.imp.con.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-34-thread-1)     CH step (5), time spent (54454), score (-3360hard/-14medium/-300soft), selected move count (5), picked move (Bari Centrale 2024-10-02T22:00+02:00 to 2024-10-03T06:00+02:00 {null -> Roberto Benigni (E2)}).

It seems as if the groupBy of my new constraint affects somehow the grouping of the max-hours-per-day constraint which does not make any sense. For completeness the max-hours-per-day constraint is the following:
Constraint dailyHoursMustNotExceedEmploymentRuleMaximum(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Employee.class)
                .filter(employee -> employee.getEmploymentRule().getMaximumHoursPerDay() != null)
                .join(Shift.class, equal(Function.identity(), Shift::getEmployee))
                .groupBy((employee, shift) -> employee,
                        (employee, shift) -> shift.getStartDateTime().toLocalDate(),
                        sumDuration((employee, shift) -> {
                            Duration allDuration = between(shift.getStartDateTime(), shift.getEndDateTime());
                            Duration breakDuration = Duration.ZERO;
                            for (ShiftBreak shiftBreak : shift.getShiftBreaks()) {
                                breakDuration = between(shiftBreak.getStartedAt(), shiftBreak.getEndedAt());
                            }
                            return allDuration.minus(breakDuration);
                        }))
                .filter((employee, firstDayOfWeek, totalWorkingTime) -> totalWorkingTime.toMinutes() >
                        (long) employee.getEmploymentRule().getMaximumHoursPerDay() * DateTimeUtils.MINUTES_PER_HOUR)
                .penalizeConfigurableLong(CONSTRAINT_DAILY_HOURS_MUST_NOT_EXCEED_EMPLOYMENT_RULE_MAXIMUM,
                        (employee, firstDayOfWeek, totalWorkingTime) -> {
                            long excessMinutes = totalWorkingTime.toMinutes() - (long) employee.getEmploymentRule().getMaximumHoursPerDay() * DateTimeUtils.MINUTES_PER_HOUR;
                            return excessMinutes;
                        });
    }

Footnote: without the hack I've used and annotated in my constraint, the soft penalty calculations demonstrate a similar wrong behavior.
I know I've written a lot and still haven't given you anything to play with.. Not sure how/if I could do that. Still any help would be hugely appreciated!!
Panos

OptaPlanner 8.23 is an ancient version of an already pretty much abandoned project. (No releases for over a year.) Timefold Solver is the maintained, fully supported fork of OptaPlanner. The behavior described may very well be a bug, and that bug may very well be fixed in Timefold Solver. Also, Timefold Solver has a Consecutive Collector which may solve your issue altogether.
